# Getting rid of "My Computer " window after login

Tags: windows-xp

Soon after I login to my Windows XP machine, a "My Computer" window always pops up. I've tried to remove it from autorunning, but it didn't have any effect.

Any idea how I can stop the window showing up every time?

Answer (score 2):

You might look into [Sysinternals/Microsoft Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) tool.  It is a great application that will show you all of the different things that are being started when your computer starts.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not being opened by something in the Autoruns, you (or someone else) may have checked the "Restore previous folder" option in the Folder Options.

Open Windows Explorer (doubleclick "My Computer"); in the Tools menu, select Folder Options; select the View tab; scroll to the bottom of the list; make sure "Restore previous folder windows at logon" is unchecked.  Click OK.

[image: scroll to the bottom to find the option]

Comment: Thank you fo rthe response , I checked if the Restore previous folder windows at logon is Check marked BUT IT WAS ALREADY UNCHECKED :(.

Comment: no problem.  sounds like heavyd's suggestion of `Autoruns` will work better for you.  good luck!